# Change the text from a file

Tags: python

Data form like this:

```
line1
text1
text2
line2
something text1

line3
```

Making an output:

```
line1 text1 text2
line2 something text1

line3
```

how could I make it to delete?

Comment: Your question is **very** hard to understand. I tried my best to answer but I'm not sure whether I understood what you meant. I suggest you try to clarify your question.

Comment: You should either accept one of the questions as being correct or clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Removing blank lines can be done as such:

```
with open('input') as fin, open('output', 'w') as fout:
    non_blank = (line for line in fin if line.strip())
    fout.writelines(non_blank)
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* your goal is to delete the blank like, right? If that's the case:

```
inputfile = open('example.txt', 'r')
outputfile = open('examplelines.txt', 'w')

for line in inputfile:
    if line.strip('\n') != '':
        outputfile.write(line)

inputfile.close()
outputfile.close()
```

Comment: `if not line.strip():` would be more concise.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this does what you want:

```
import sys

i = 2
for line in sys.stdin:
    if line.startswith('line%d' % i):
        i += 1
        sys.stdout.write('\n')
    if line == '\n':
        sys.stdout.write('\n')
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(line.rstrip() + ' ')

sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

This runs through the input lines and collects text until it finds an input line that says `lineN`. Such a line begins a new line in the input. Furthermore, a blank line in the input is passed through as a blank line in the output.